# Why do we set controller variables equal to "this" in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

So I am looking at an example in codeschools staying sharp with angular in section 1.5. 
Heres the code:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.controller('NotesIndexController', function($http) {
    var controller = this;
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'}).success(function(data){
        controller.notes = data;
    })
 });
```

I read Mozilla's developer networks guide to [this][1] but my understanding is still not great.

In the following line from the above example.

```
var controller = this;
```

**Why are we setting controller = to this? Why not just have var controller;?** or is by setting it equal to this making it a global variable otherwise in the success callback that would just be changing its own local controller variable not the one declared in the controller?

They later do the following in the html if it provides any clues:

```
<div class="note-wrapper">
    <a class ="card-notes" ng-repeat="notes in indexController.notes">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not just have var controller;?

Because that means `controller` would be `undefined`.

```js
var controller;
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = controller;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

> is by setting it equal to this making it a global variable

You're not creating a *global* variable but you are creating a [*closed over*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) variable. This means that you can use that value in your callback. In order to use that value in a callback, you either need to create a closure variable or bind the function.

```js
var controller = {
  hello: 'world'
};

// Just so we have to use a callback
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(this);
}, 0);

// Using a closure variable
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(controller);
}, 0);

// Binding a function
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(this);
}.bind(controller), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting variables to `this` allows you to add new namespaces when using the `controllerAs` syntax.

```
function OneCtrl() {
    this.notes = "foo";
}

function TwoCtrl() {
    this.notes = "bar";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="OneCtrl as ctrl1">
    {{ctrl1.notes}}
    <div ng-controller="TwoCtrl as ctrl2">
        {{ctrl2.notes}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Without `controllerAs`, you'd have to make use of `$parent`, which is actually bad practice.  Imaging having to use `$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.someValue`.

Further reading: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/02/exploring-angular-s-controller-as-syntax-and-the-vm-variable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> is by setting it equal to this making it a global variable otherwise in the success callback that would just be changing its own local controller variable not the one declared in the controller?

The value of `this` depends on how a function is called.

When you have a new function, you have a new value for `this` inside it.

Storing it in another variable means that the inner function can read the value of that variable (since it doesn't have access to the same `this`).

It isn't a global though, just a variable in a wider scope.